# use preg_replace and add class for a specific domain name

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for solution to change all img tags where is src imgur.
I have try this and generaly this is working, but problem can be if imgur change their subdomain in this case this regex wont work.

So to be more clear i just need to add class name too all images hosted on imgur.

```
$string = 'I have been searching <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NknpNdu.jpg" alt=""> for...';
$regex = '#<img src="https://i.imgur.com([^"/]*/?[^".]*\.[^"]*)"([^>]*)>#';
$replace = '<img class="newClass" src="https://i.imgur.com/$1">';
$Content = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this expression

```
(<img src=".*?imgur\.com(.*?))(?=\/?\s?>)
```

with a replacement of `$1 class="newClass"` might just work OK.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/dbGpka/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(<img src=".*?imgur\.com(.*?))(?=\/?\s?>)/s';
$str = 'I have been searching <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NknpNdu.jpg" alt=""> for... I have been searching <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NknpNdu.jpg" alt=""> for... I have been searching <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NknpNdu.jpg" alt=""> for... I have been searching <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NknpNdu.jpg" alt="" /> for... ';
$subst = '$1 class="newClass"';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

Or more simplified, with less boundaries, this expression:

```
(<img .*?imgur\.com(.*?))(?=\/?\s?>)
```

would do the same.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OppV0W/1/)

Comment: What is subdomain is not i. in that case regex wont work?

Comment: I think this is working fine, you can update your answer so i can accep it...